# graphviz_layout: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_node'

Tags: python, networkx, graphviz

For some reason when i try to implement this function in my dynamically created graph, I get this weird error. I can run the function examples given online but its fails when I run it.

stacktrace:

```
    122     #pos = nx.spectral_layout(G)
    123     #write_dot(G,'test.dot')
--> 124     pos= graphviz_layout(G,prog='twopi',args='')
    125     nx.draw_networkx(G, node_color=nodeColors, arrows=False, alpha=.8, labels=nodeLabels, font_size=8)
    126     print(nx.info(G))

    246     This is a wrapper for pydot_layout.
    247     """
--> 248     return pydot_layout(G=G,prog=prog,root=root,**kwds)
    249 
    250 

    281     for n in G.nodes():
    282         pydot_node = pydotplus.Node(make_str(n)).get_name()
--> 283         node=Q.get_node(pydot_node)
    284 
    285         if isinstance(node,list):

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_node'
```

Answer (score 0):

Without understanding more about the code, it is hard to say what caused the problem, but...

Based on the error message and the stacktrace, the object 'Q' is set to `None`. For some reason, when the object Q was made, the code assigned the value `None` instead of the desired value. Troubleshooting will require backtracking to find out when Q was made and why it was set to `None`.

`--> 283         node=Q.get_node(pydot_node)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like this is a simple typo.  You wrote `Q` where you probably meant `G`.  There is nothing called `Q`, and so `Q.get_node` makes no sense.  However `G.get_node` would make sense.

Comment: I would think that if the `Q` were simply a typo, then the error would be:
`NameError: name 'Q' is not defined` instead of: 
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_node'`.
Python's execution path should detect the fact that Q is not defined before attempting to find an attribute on that object.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Joel may not be correct, since from the source, it shows that

```
P=to_pydot(G)
if root is not None :
    P.set("root",make_str(root))

D=P.create_dot(prog=prog)

if D=="":  # no data returned
    print("Graphviz layout with %s failed"%(prog))
    print()
    print("To debug what happened try:")
    print("P=pydot_from_networkx(G)")
    print("P.write_dot(\"file.dot\")")
    print("And then run %s on file.dot"%(prog))
    return

Q=pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(D)

node_pos={}
for n in G.nodes():
    pydot_node = pydotplus.Node(make_str(n)).get_name()
    node=Q.get_node(pydot_node)
```

So Q plays no direct role with the eternal